# Getting HttpRequestMessage when using IActionFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I extract the `HttpRequestMessage` from the `ActionExecutedContext` or `ActionExecutingContext`  when using a `IActionFilter`

Comment: Did you check in `context.Request`?

Comment: Is it WebApi or MVC?

Comment: The project is a MVC project